# How do I mask Facebook graph api URLs for pictures?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, http, facebook-graph-api

I'm trying to display Facebook profile pictures on my site, but don't want to leak the facebook id's of the people in the source.

For example, this URL: http://graph.facebook.com/4/picture will redirect to: http://profile.ak.fbcdn.net/hprofile-ak-snc4/157340_4_3955636_q.jpg when you load it in a browser. I'd like to get the 2nd url (CDN url) and use it as my img src since it doesn't show the facebook id in the url.

I'm doing this in Ruby on Rails at the moment and am curious if there's a better way that what I have done below:

```
def picture_square(facebook_id, secure=false)
  raw_url = "http://graph.facebook.com/" facebook_id + "/picture?type=square"
  if secure
    binary_img = ''
    open(raw_url) do |f|
      binary_img = f.read
    end
    encoded_img = Base64.encode64(binary_img)
    return 'data:image/jpg;base64,' + encoded_img.to_s
  else
    return raw_url
  end
end
```

You could call this with the following HTML (using the above example):

```
<img src="<%= picture_square(4, true) %>"
```

This definitely works and uses the inline image properties to actually render the image, but it's a bit slow if you have a bunch of images that you're trying to load.

Is there a way in Ruby that I can get the redirected URL and just return that instead of trying to get the actual raw binary data and encode it to base64?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make a call to the graph API with this url:
http://graph.facebook.com/4/?fields=picture&type=large

This will return the image you are looking for inside the json response.  The other option would be to make an http request to the first url you posted and then inspect the HTTP headers to read the location header..