# Cannot fetch large type picture for multiple Facebook object ids Graph API

Tags: facebook-graph-api, object, types, image

I just can't figure it out, i am using Facebook graph API to fetch data, lets say i have a multiple Facebook objects and i want their picture in type=large...
I saw some posts like this one 
[How do I mask Facebook graph api URLs for pictures?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9829259/how-do-i-mask-facebook-graph-api-urls-for-pictures)
That suggesting to do the following: /?ids=OBJECT_IDS&fields=picture&type=large 
The thing is that it seems the once the picture is specified as a field like the above the type URL parameter doesn't seem to effect the retrieved picture.

If there is a way to fetch large type pictures of multiple Facebook objects in one request via the graph API please let me know...

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

All you really need is the object's id.

- If its a user then his/her `user_id`.
- If its a page then the `page_id`.
- etc...

Once you have that you can simply use this URL to get the large image -

```
https://graph.facebook.com/OBJECT_ID/picture?type=large
```

You don't really have to request the large image as you can place this URL directly as a link to the image.  In HTML for example -

```
<img src="https://graph.facebook.com/4/picture?type=large" />
```

---

The problem with obtaining **all** the large images of different types of object is that they are all located at different endpoints.  You would be able to get multiple pictures for the **same type** of object. For example -

- by `user_id`

  `select pic_big from user where uid in(4,5,6)`
- by `page_id`

  `select pic_big from page where page_id in(1,2,3)`
- by `event_id`

  `select pic_big from event where eid in(1,2,3)`
- by `group_id`

  `select pic_big from group where gid in(1,2,3)`

Comment: Thank you for your response... that i already know... i want to fetch pictures of few objects in one request...

Comment: something like... https://graph.facebook.com/?ids=4,5,6&fields=picture?type=large

Comment: Are you looking for user pictures or page pictures or both?

Comment: Also, is there any reason you have to get all of the images at once?

Comment: thanks again... the thing about the pic_big column is "maximum width of 200px and a maximum height of 600px" is there any relation from page to the photo_id ? in order to use photo_src to get the wanted height & width ... like in picture&height=X&width=Y?

Comment: There is another possibility.. to use batch request which will contains specific request for each object

Comment: like /OBJECT_ID/picture?hieght=X&width=Y ... you think it will be an overhead?

Comment: If you want the pic_src, you'll have to do an additional call to the photo table with the photo_id... Batch requests might work but you would have to make alot of requests and I'm not sure of the limit on batch requests...

Comment: but from where i get the photo id related to pic_big string URL at these tables?

Comment: I'm afraid I can't see a way to get that data the way you want it (all at once)... To get the original source of a persons profile picture, you would have to scan through their albums, find one called "Profile Pictures", and look at the first item - thats the current profile picture, from there you extract the photo_id and with that you query the photo table to get the `pic_src` field... I can't think of any way to shorten that path...

Comment: Maybe the FQL `profile_pic` table offers a shorter path to user profile pictures; https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/profile_pic/